Can a 4066 IC work at 3.3V?
I am trying to incorporate a CD4066 in my circuit to switch a 3.3V signal. I am bad at reading datasheets but I think this datasheet says this IC works with 5V-15V between VDD and GND pins of the IC. I have till now used it with 3.3V between VDD and GND pins of the IC without trouble. Is it advisable to use it at 5-15V only?

What Rds(on) do you need? Switching speed?

@TimWilliams honestly I don't know what Rds on is. I'm not an electronics engineer. And I'd like it to switch as fast as is possible.

Well, I can guarantee you CD4066 won't achieve that. "As fast as possible" is perhaps 100ps for a device of this type of design; significantly less for esoteric (optical switching) methods.  Needless to say, the latter get very expensive very quickly. Are you sure you need "as fast as possible"?  Put another way: if you asked every car dealer "I need to go as fast as possible", and you got quoted a Bugatti for a cool $million, would that be a meaningful option for you?  Or are you really just driving to get groceries and "fast enough given X" is really what you're after here?

@TimWilliams I get your point. I don't think I need a Bugatti level IC, considering my work is handled fine by even the switching at 3.3V supply. I could power the IC with 5V supply for what is I guess would be marginal improvement but then I'd need level shifters for switching signals from the microcontroller because I am using ESP32 dev module and it works at 3.3V.

As the recommended operating conditions in the data sheet are 3 V to 18 V, you can expect it to function at 3.3 V.
However, switching speed, Ron, and Ron match are only specified at 5, 10 and 15 V. At 3.3 V you will get whatever you get. Expect speed and Ron to be inferior to use at 5 V.
You could also try a 74HC4066, which is specified at 2 V, 4.5 V and 6 V supply, and is pin compatible.

got it, thanks...

Recommended operating conditions say that 18 V > VDD-VSS > 3 V.
So, it is also for VDD alone.
So, yes it can work. See also others recommendations.
